# Android ToggleButton indicator

Tags: android, togglebutton

I'm struggling with the Android ToggleButton because I try to change the green indicator light. In the Android SDK folder I've found the file drawable\btn_toggle_bg.xml where it says

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:id="@+android:id/background" android:drawable="@android:drawable/btn_default_small" /> 
  <item android:id="@+android:id/toggle" android:drawable="@android:drawable/btn_toggle" /> 
</layer-list>
```

I copied this file to the drawable folder of my project and changed the last item to

```
<item android:id="@+android:id/toggle" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_toggle" />
```

and then took the original btn_toggle.xml from the Android SDK, copied into the drawable folder, too. btn_toggle.xml is this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_toggle_off" /> 
  <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_toggle_on" /> 
</selector>
```

So then I asumed that it would be necessary to create btn_toggle_off.png and btn_toggle_on.png. At last I added the line

```
<ToggleButton
...
android:background="@drawable/btn_toggle_bg" />
```

but finally, the ToggleButton looks completely strange. 
What I noticed are files called btn_toggle_off.9.png and btn_toggle_on.9.png in the SDK but I couldn't find a reference to these files although they look exactely like the original indicator.

Can you help me? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without completely re-styling the toggle button widget, the resources you are trying to replace should probably be nine patch PNGs like the originals are.

Copy `btn_toggle_off.9.png` and `btn_toggle_on.9.png` into your project and modify them, or use the `draw9patch` tool to properly add the nine patch metadata to your own images.

Refer to the following documentation for an explaination of Android's nine patch drawables:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

The ".9" part of the filename must be retained, but is not referenced in XML resources. So `btn_toggle_on.9.png` is referred to as simply `"@drawable/btn_toggle_on"`.